# Insertar datos desde java en MySQL

Tags: java

He mirado otras alternativas de preguntas que se han hecho aquí sin poder obtener una solución. Mi duda viene a la hora de insertar datos de un array. En el propio programa de Java, se crea una tabla (si es que no existe) y después pasa a introducir todos los datos que hay guardados en el array, pero no inserta nada.

El código que tengo:

```
public class Conectate {
    private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/Blog";
    private String pass = "";
    private String usuario = "root";
    public Connection con;

    public Conectate(String[][] listaEmpresaA) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
            System.out.println("¡Conectado!");

            //CREAMOS LA TABLA
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Xbox_One (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY(id), Juego VARCHAR(500), URL VARCHAR (200), Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50), Descripcion TEXT(5000),"
                + "Pegi VARCHAR(10), Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR (200), nota FLOAT(10,1),"
                + "USA VARCHAR (100), USA_Gold VARCHAR (100), USA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), USA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "ARG VARCHAR (100), ARG_Gold VARCHAR (100), ARG_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), ARG_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "AUS VARCHAR (100), AUS_Gold VARCHAR (100), AUS_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), AUS_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "BRA VARCHAR (100), BRA_Gold VARCHAR (100), BRA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), BRA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CAN VARCHAR (100), CAN_Gold VARCHAR (100), CAN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CAN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "SIN VARCHAR (100), SIN_Gold VARCHAR (100), SIN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), SIN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "ESP VARCHAR (100), ESP_Gold VARCHAR (100), ESP_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), ESP_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "HK VARCHAR (100), HK_Gold VARCHAR (100), HK_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), HK_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "MEX VARCHAR (100), MEX_Gold VARCHAR (100), MEX_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), MEX_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "COL VARCHAR (100), COL_Gold VARCHAR (100), COL_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), COL_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "HUN VARCHAR (100), HUN_Gold VARCHAR (100), HUN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), HUN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "SUD VARCHAR (100), SUD_Gold VARCHAR (100), SUD_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), SUD_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "RUS VARCHAR (100), RUS_Gold VARCHAR (100), RUS_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), RUS_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CHI VARCHAR (100), CHI_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHI_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHI_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "IND VARCHAR (100), IND_Gold VARCHAR (100), IND_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), IND_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "JP VARCHAR (100), JP_Gold VARCHAR (100), JP_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), JP_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "KOR VARCHAR (100), KOR_Gold VARCHAR (100), KOR_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), KOR_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "TAI VARCHAR (100), TAI_Gold VARCHAR (100), TAI_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), TAI_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "UK VARCHAR (100), UK_Gold VARCHAR (100), UK_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), UK_EA VARCHAR (100))");

            System.out.println("Tabla creada!");    

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Xbox_One (Juego, URL, Publicado, Lanzamiento, Descripcion, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi, nota, "
                + "USA, USA_Gold, USA_sin_Gold, USA_EA, ARG, ARG_Gold, ARG_sin_Gold, ARG_EA,"
                + "AUS, AUS_Gold, AUS_sin_Gold, AUS_EA, BRA, BRA_Gold, BRA_sin_Gold, BRA_EA,"
                + "CAN, CAN_Gold, CAN_sin_Gold, CAN_EA, SIN, SIN_Gold, SIN_sin_Gold, SIN_EA,"
                + "ESP, ESP_Gold, ESP_sin_Gold, ESP_EA, HK, HK_Gold, HK_sin_Gold, HK_EA,"
                + "MEX, MEX_Gold, MEX_sin_Gold, MEX_EA, COL, COL_Gold, COL_sin_Gold, COL_EA,"
                + "HUN, HUN_Gold, HUN_sin_Gold, HUN_EA, SUD, SUD_Gold, SUD_sin_Gold, SUD_EA,"
                + "RUS, RUS_Gold, RUS_sin_Gold, RUS_EA, CHI, CHI_Gold, CHI_sin_Gold, CHI_EA,"
                + "CHINA, CHINA_Gold, CHINA_sin_Gold, CHINA_EA, IND, IND_Gold, IND_sin_Gold, IND_EA,"
                + "JP, JP_Gold, JP_sin_Gold, JP_EA, KOR, KOR_Gold, KOR_sin_Gold, KOR_EA,"
                + "TAI, TAI_Gold, TAI_sin_Gold, TAI_EA, UK, UK_Gold, UK_sin_Gold, UK_EA)"
                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                + ",?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                + ",?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            for(String[] array : listaEmpresaA) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 95; ++i) { //Careful to an             arrayoutofbounds exception, but every parameter MUST BE SET
                    ps.setString(i + 2, array[i]); //Can't be null, if so, must use setNull(i+1);
                }
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB");
        }    
    }

    public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
        String Str = "";
        if(Obj != null) {
            Str = Obj.toString();
        }
        return Str;
    }    
}
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda. He conseguido insertar datos sueltos metiéndolos a mano pero en éste caso no.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tu nunca colocas el valor para el primer parámetro del `PreparedStatement`. Ademas, si cuento bien, tienes 22*4 = 88 valores para poner en el `ps`, sí to codigo tuviera más sentido si se veía asi:

```
    for(String[] array : listaEmpresaA){
        for(int i = 0; i < 88; i++){
            // Careful to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            if (array[i]!=null || i >= array.length){
                ps.setString(i+1, array[i]);
            } else {
                ps.setNull(i+1);
            }
        //Can't be null, if so, must use setNull(i+1);
        }
    ps.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Alguien que te quiere ahorrar dolores de cabeza te regaló comentarios en ingles, me tomé la libertad de pescarlos para ti.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta! No te he respondido hasta ahora porque no he llegado a ese punto del código, es decir, me está dando problemas al compilar, aunque tienes razón que me había confundido en el tamaño de la tabla, lo tengo ya corregido!